# Blured background behind the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a pop up that will appear immediately after loading the page. In addition, I want the background behind the black div to be blured, unfortunately after using filter = blur (8px) whole page is blured.
Help...

```js
window.onload = function main(){
document.body.style.backdropFilter="blur(5px)"
    document.body.style.background="red"
   const add = document.createElement('div')
   const overall = document.createElement('div')


   overall.style.width="100%"
   overall.style.height="95vh"
   overall.style.justifyContent="center"
   overall.style.display="flex"
   overall.style.alignItems="center"
  overall.filter="blur(8px)"
  overall.style.backgroundImage="url(https://www.hgsm.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Pattern-Blue-Dots-background-patterns-pattern-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpg)"



   add.style.display="flex"
   add.style.justifyContent="center"
   add.style.alignItems="center"
   add.style.width="300px"
   add.style.height="400px"
   add.style.background="black"


   const element = document.createElement("img") ;
 


   document.body.appendChild(overall)
   overall.appendChild(add)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OptAd</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're blurring the body, and the body happens to contain your black div. You'll need to put what you want to blur in its own container, and blur that container instead

Comment: it doesn't matter even if it only overall div is blured black div i also blured look, I changed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `backdrop-filter` on your overlay element (the one that fully covers the window)
- Don't forget to use position `fixed` and `z-index`

```js
window.onload = function main() {
  const add = document.createElement('div')
  const overall = document.createElement('div')

  overall.style.cssText = `
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  `;
  add.style.cssText = `
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background: white;
  `;
  add.textContent = "HELLO, WORLD?"
  overall.appendChild(add);
  document.body.appendChild(overall);
  document.body.style.background = "red"
}
```

```html
<h1>This is some body text</h1>
```

If you want a more Class-y approach:

```js
class Modal {
  constructor(htmlContent) {
    this.EL_overlay = document.createElement('div');
    this.EL_content = document.createElement('div');
    this.EL_content.innerHTML = htmlContent || "";
    this.EL_overlay.append(this.EL_content);
    this.EL_overlay.style.cssText = `
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1000;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    `;
    this.EL_content.style.cssText = `
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      overflow: auto;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 50vw;
      height: 50vh;
      background: #ddd;
    `;
  }
  show() {
    document.body.append(this.EL_overlay);
  }
  hide() {
    this.EL_overlay.remove();
  }
};

const myModal = new Modal("HELLO, <b>WORLD</b>?");
myModal.show();
```

```html
<h1>This is some body text</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

backdrop will do the trick

```
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
```